# iPhone: How to change font color in UITableViewCell when selected?

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableViewCell with labels inside my contentview. When I set the cell selection style to gray or blue, I want the font color in the label to be white. How can I do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use

```
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Works as expected in UICollectionView as well. Spent along time with, didSelectItemAtIndexPath, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath etc and all i needed was this.

Comment: if you have set cellselectionstylenone it will not work

Answer (score 6):

This can also be done directly in Interface Builder. Just select the cell's title or subtitle label, flip to the Attributes inspector, and select the color with this control:

[image: Highlighted color selector in Interface Builder]

Answer (score 1):

override the method `-(void)setselected:(Bool)flag` method. change the font